# Mount images with network volumes

Tags: docker, hyper-v, nas

I'm trying to mount a gitlab image in docker, I want it to have the repositories in a NAS, which I have in the local network, well, in case of disaster the information is not lost, I just have to reinstall the docker and run.

All this explained below with WINDOWS 10 PRO with the HYPER-V

I have tried different alternatives but they all end if they exit.

Proven and dead-end options.

- Folder shared in the NAS mounted on windows 10. -> Through the
  Kitematic can not share, only local disk.
- Mount ISCSI LUN volume on the NAS and mount as disk on the PC. From
  the point of view of windows it is like a local disk and the
  Kinematic allows to share it. Problem, that when changing the GITLAB
  so that the data folder is on this Y: drive, tells me that the disk
  is not POSIX compliant. Something that is spending the gitlab
  provided by POSIX ..
- Share NFS folder from the NAS and mount NFS type docker volume and
  use it when running the image ...-> Permission problems, the UID /
  GID do not match, even with the --privileged parameter, this drive I
  am able to mount it on Windows specifying the default UID / GID in
  regedit but I do not find, nor do I know if I can pass these values.

I have run out of ideas.